# JQuery | Takes Two Clicks to Hide Div Tag via Menu Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

On my `Contact` page I have a link to show an email form, which right now is just a header. I want the email form to hide whenever a different "page" is clicked on; however, right now it takes two clicks to get rid of the form. The form should only be visible on the `Contact Page`. I made a small testcase to illustrate the problem.

My code works, but only after you click a menu twice. I need help making it so I click a link once and it disappears.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Creighton Barbershop</title>
<link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav ul li").on("click", "a",
        function(){
                    if ($("#contact").is(":hidden")) {  
                        $(".contact_form").slideUp().hide();
                    };
            $("div.main").slideUp();
            $("div" + $(this).attr("href")).slideToggle().show().end();

            event.preventDefault();
        });

    $("#email_link").click(
        function(){
            $(".contact_form").slideToggle();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home"         id="link_to_home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about"        id="link_to_about"><span class="word_space">About Us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact"      id="link_to_contact"><span class="word_space">Contact Us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#cuts"         id="lik_to_cuts">Cuts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<hr>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main" id="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main" id="contact">
    <a href="#contact_form" id="email_link" class="email">Email Us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact_form">
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main" id="cuts">
    <h2>These are the various cuts that Rob Ecklos Specializes in./n/n</h2>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why didnt you tag jquery?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was trying to hurry up and submit it. I had a few seconds left of class. It won't let me add the tag from the app.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change a little thing in your html
just move the contact_form div inside contact div
let code like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Creighton Barbershop</title>
<link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav ul li").on("click", "a",
        function(){
                    if ($("#contact").is(":hidden")) {  
                        $(".contact_form").slideUp().hide();
                    };
            $("div.main").slideUp();
            $("div" + $(this).attr("href")).slideToggle().show().end();

            event.preventDefault();
        });

    $("#email_link").click(
        function(){
            $(".contact_form").slideToggle();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home"         id="link_to_home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about"        id="link_to_about"><span class="word_space">About Us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact"      id="link_to_contact"><span class="word_space">Contact Us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#cuts"         id="lik_to_cuts">Cuts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<hr>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main" id="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main" id="contact">
    <a href="#contact_form" id="email_link" class="email">Email Us</a>
    <div class="contact_form">
        <h1>Contact Form</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main" id="cuts">
    <h2>These are the various cuts that Rob Ecklos Specializes in./n/n</h2>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then remove the if statement form your jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav ul li").on("click", "a",
        function(){
            $(".contact_form").slideUp().hide();
            $("div.main").slideUp();
            $("div" + $(this).attr("href")).slideToggle().show().end();

            event.preventDefault();
        });

    $("#email_link").click(
        function(){
            $(".contact_form").slideToggle();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

`is(':visible')` checks the `display` property of an element, you can use `css` method.

```
//Check the visiblity of #contact and hide accordangly
if ($("#contact").css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
   $(".contact_form").slideUp().hide();
}
```

Comment: I'll try it out when I get on a PC. In the examples I looked at I was pretty sure I read that they are synonymous.

Comment: @Crysis sure, also try with visible selector in jquery https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: The code I have worked; this code doesn't. The problem with my code is that it takes two clicks to hide the email form.